# Document Routing

Tags: powerapp, approval-process

I am trying to build an automatic routing system. I know there is the approval workflow but I need those within the Routing list to be able to add comments to the attached PDF and digital sign. I am unable to use Adobe sign as it's not allow on our network yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more information in your question on what the automatic routing system needs to achieve?

Comment: I need to route a pdf document to 3 people, first to person a and then to b and c and back to me once completed. This pdf is a evaluation form where each person needs to add comments and sign the PDF.